# How can I create a Keen IO query with "OR" filters?

Tags: analytics, keen-io, nosql

I was wondering if the Filters in Keen IO queries can be done as "OR".

Basically, I have a "column" ([event property](https://keen.io/docs/streams/data-modeling-guide/#event-properties)) called "product_type".

I want to generate an API Query URL that has an extraction with a filter that is "if product_type equals x OR product_type equals y".

But right now, if I do a Filter like that, it's always "AND".

Answer (score 2):

Use the the "in" operator. This "in" operator will identify any events where the property *equals* any value in a list, like this:

```
var extraction = new Keen.Query("extraction", {
  event_collection: "purchases",
  timeframe: "this_14_days",
  filters: [
    {
      property_name: "product_type",
      operator: "in",
      property_value: ["x","y"]
    }
  ]
});
```

Here's a handy list of all of the available filter [operators](https://keen.io/docs/api/#filters).